# Adding data attributes to a html string not on the dom with jQuery in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, coffeescript

I wrote a function that takes a collection of json and a html template string.   I want to be able to iterate over the collection and set the 'data-adq-uuid' to the uuid of the json model and set any attributes that match input fields from the template.  The method seems to be working in some way because on a click callback the data() is showing the proper uuid attribute being set however the html is not being updated.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/frmsk8na/6/
You can see that when you click save the uuid is being alerted but it is not present in the html.

Class and function:

```
class Invoice

  @append_html_from_collection: (collection, template) ->
    $($.parseJSON(collection)).each (i, model) ->
      $template = $(template)
      $template.find("[data-adq-uuid]").each (i, elem) ->
        $template.find(elem).replaceWith($(elem).data("adq-uuid", model.uuid))
      $.each model, (key, value) ->
        input = $(template).find("input[data-attr='" + key + "']")
        if input.length
          $template.find("input[data-attr='" + key + "']").val(value)

      $("#invoice-table").append($template)
```

Data to be passed in:

```
collection = '[{"id":28,"uuid":"6683aaee-642d-4484-9edc-4ae7da866367","invoice_id":1,"description":"something","qty":2,"price_cents":500,"total_cents":1000,"created_at":"2014-11-15T04:57:20.277Z","updated_at":"2014-11-15T04:57:20.277Z"},{"id":null,"uuid":"128b0360-3c5f-4ed4-84f1-5bd3c5d21685","invoice_id":null,"description":null,"qty":null,"price_cents":null,"total_cents":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]'
template = '<tr>        <td><input data-adq-uuid="null" data-attr="description" data-class="line_item" data-id="null" id="description" name="description" type="text" /></td>        <td><input data-adq-uuid="null" data-attr="qty" data-class="line_item" data-id="null" id="qty" name="qty" type="text" /></td>        <td><input data-adq-uuid="null" data-attr="price_cents" data-class="line_item" data-id="null" id="price_cents" name="price_cents" type="text" /></td>        <td><a class="persist" data-adq-uuid="" href="#">Save</a></td>      </tr>'
```

Calling the function:

`Invoice.append_html_from_collection(collection, template)`

Listener to show that the data is on the element:

```
$(document).on "click", ".persist", (evt) ->
  alert $(@).data("adq-uuid")
```

Html table:

```
<table>
  <tbody id="invoice-table">
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you might find this a lot easier if you scoped the template rendering to an instance of the class, rather than a static. Because you then have the notion of `this`. Would you be open to a refactor? (or better said, what you need is an invoice item view).

Comment: Sure I am open to a refactor but I am not interested in using any tech outside of jQuery and coffeescript.  (i.e. no angular or ember or handlebars)